# How Do I Parse a Table in a Gmail email to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, automation, gmail

I do volunteer work for an animal rescue group and the main city shelter sends us an email every hour to our Gmail account that includes a table of data with information on every animal in the shelter.

I'd like to be able to open the email; parse the table that is in the content; and import the data into a MySQL database.

I've checked some Zapier scripts, and I've done it successfully using iMacros but I'd like to do it on the server side or with a 3rd party integration... or even better run the whole thing from my web hosting server.

I'm a volunteer, so I'm looking for something free. Any suggestions on doing this server side with PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php